# Programming using NVDA screen reader

Tags: python, python-2.7, add-on, screen-readers, nvda

I want NVDA to speak out whenever I start a `for` loop in my python code. How can I do this programmatically as an addon? Any kind of help appreciated.

For instance,
I type in the text editor:

`for i in range(0,3):
print "hello world"`

As soon as I am done writing `for`, NVDA should speak out that the for loop has started.

Answer (score 0):

While you might need to work with a specific TTS module of some sorts, to produce spoken output, a trick I use to let me know when tasks/activities have finished off in background is to use print(chr(7)) - evokes windows default beep sound, if you are working under windows, but, presume you are if you mention using NVDA - I use it myself, currently under windows 10